# 3rd party frameworks vs private frameworks?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I heard that apps that use private frameworks can not be submitted to Apple's App Store. So, just to help clear this up for someone new to iOS programming (have never submitted an app for approval yet), I am wondering: 1) what is the difference between a third party framework and a private framework? 2) is Parse private or 3rd party?

thanks

Comment: It's not "private frameworks" that cannot be used, but rather apps that use "private API" within Cocoa Touch. Bottom line, Apple has a bunch of API that is not public, which you're not allowed to use. But regarding third party frameworks/libraries, you can use those as you see fit (assuming they conform to Apple's guidelines, themselves). Bottom line, Parse is fine. Section 2.5 of the [App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) is talking about Apple's private API, not third party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) what is the difference between a third party framework and a private framework?

- Third party framework is written by some developer **with iOS SDK** to packet some features so that you do not need to rewrite it.For example with AFNetworking,it is more easy to write code about network
- Private framework is some API **not in public iOS SDK**.

2) is Parse private or 3rd party?

- Parse acts the backend of App. Their iOS **sdk is third party SDK.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response. Could you please tell me if the SwiftBond framework mentioned here is 3rd party or private? https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond